# Editmode in jquery popup does not work

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, popup, edit

Here is the LinkButton and it opens a popup.

```html
<asp:LinkButton ID="libKlient" OnClick="libKlient_Click" runat="server" /></td>
```

I have this jquery popup:

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="scripts/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function pop() {
            $("#dialog").dialog({
                title: "Klient",
                buttons: {
                    Close: function () {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        };
    </script>
```

and here all the Label in the div Container (ID=Dialog):

```html
 <div id="dialog" style="display: none;">
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlDialog" runat="server">
            <h1>Klient
            </h1>
            <table>

                <tr>
                    <td>Name:</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Adress:</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ReadOnly="true" ID="txtAdress" runat="server" /></td>
                </tr>
 <tr>
                    <td>Phone:</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ReadOnly="true" ID="txtPhone" runat="server" /></td>
                </tr>
 <tr>
                    <td>Email:</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ReadOnly="true" ID="txtEmail" runat="server" /></td>
                </tr>
 <tr>
                    <td>Birtday:</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ReadOnly="true" ID="txtBirtday" runat="server" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        
        <asp:Button Text="Edit" ID="btnEdit" OnClick="btnEdit_Click" runat="server" />
    </asp:Panel></div>
```

And here is the Sqldatereader, who reads the Labels. So if user clicks on the LinkButton(libKlient) the popup Pops out and all the textboxes are enabled=false. And until here everything works!

```html
protected void libKlient_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "Show Modal Popup", "pop();", true);

        string sql = "Select * From Klient WHERE Name=@Name";
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Conn"].ConnectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", GridView1.SelectedDataKey.Values[3].ToString());

                using (SqlDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (r.Read())
                    {
                        try
                        {

                            txtName.Text = r["Name"].ToString();
                            txtName.Enabled = false;

                            txtAdress.Text = r["Adress"].ToString();
                            txtAdress.Enabled = false;

              txtPhone.Text = r["Phone"].ToString();
                            txtPhone.Enabled = false;

                            txtEmail.Text = r["Email"].ToString();
                            txtEmail.Enabled = false;

                      txtBirtday.Text = r["Birtday"].ToString();
                            txtBirtday.Enabled = false;

                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            con.Close();
        }


    }
```

The Problem is the edit button (ID= btnEdit). I want that if I click on the button all the textboxes will get from enabled false = enabled true. But it does not work. As soon as I click on the edit button the popup Closes:

```html
protected void Read(Control control)
    {
        foreach (Control c in control.Controls)
        {
            if (c is TextBox && c.ID.StartsWith("txt"))
                ((TextBox)c).Enabled = true;
        }
    }

    protected void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Read(pnlDialog);
    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET WebForms every page has a `form` and communication issued by the client is generally done by posting that `form`. The server receives everything, but the page sent as a response will not have the popup opened in your current code. You can achieve what you want by calling `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` at `btnEdit_Click` like you already did at `libKlient_Click`.

Alternatively, you can add a `CssClass` value, maybe editable to your `TextBox` controls and change your button to something like this

```
<asp:Button Text="Edit" ID="btnEdit" OnClientClick="enableEditable(); return false;" runat="server" />
```

where `enableEditable` is

```
function enableEditable() {
    $(".editable").removeAttr("disabled");
}
```